# Oracle Trigger creation with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to create a simple trigger with following code -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_menu_id BEFORE INSERT ON "menu" FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SELECT
    menu_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO : NEW.MENU_ID
 FROM
    dual ;
END ;
```

But I am getting - [Err] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: pay attention to colon before NEW. There should not be any space there. Also, is your table really named "menu" in lowercase?

Comment: I have also tried by removing space after colon. But same result. Yes table name is in lowercase

Comment: please post the complete error output. run : Show errors after the trigger execution to get complete output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last my problem is solved. Field name was in small letter so I have to use `NEW."menu_id"` instead of `NEW.MENU_ID` and now it works fine!!!
My new code is-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_menu_id BEFORE INSERT ON "menu" FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SELECT
    menu_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW."menu_id"
 FROM
    dual ;
END ;
```